# .htaccess url rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

here i am trying to rewrite url but its not working

```
> Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine on rewriterule
> ^FAQ.php?view=why_best(.*)$ http://www.bestsports.ca/FAQ/WhyBest$1
> [r=301,nc]
```

old url is http://www.bestsports.ca/FAQ.php?view=why_best

New Url http://www.bestsports.ca/FAQ/WhyBest should be like this

after editing htacces fiel its opening the same old url please help

thanks

i am trying this code now

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+FAQ\.php\?view=why_best [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /FAQ/WhyBest/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^FAQ/WhyBest/?$ /FAQ.php?view=why_best [QSA,NC,L]


RewriteRule ^ /FAQ/SizeChart/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^FAQ/SizeChart/?$ /FAQ.php?view=size_chart [QSA,NC,L]
```

but its showing error

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

and if i click same link again for FAQ.php?view=why_best  its

redirected to

http://www.bestsports.ca/FAQ/WhyBest/FAQ.php?view=why_best

as you helped me i completed the above seo url rewrite problem for my all other website pages

i used the third party cart system from ecwid when i click on any proudct its show this link or url

```
http://www.bestsports.ca/product.php#!/~/product/category=9414048&id=11484861
```

how can i rewrite this url insted of showing category id and  i want to show name 
i already tried your above instruction but its not working can you please explain is it possible to make this url seo friendly url

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`. Use `RewriteCond` instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+FAQ\.php\?view=why_best [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /FAQ/WhyBest? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^FAQ/WhyBest/?$ /FAQ.php?view=why_best [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: its working fine but after that page showing this error... Not Found

The requested URL /FAQ/WhyBest was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: its working.. but its redirecting me to ripped css and html page of html .. maybe its not passing value why_best.

Comment: but i set default page for empty passing value.. instead of showing me default page its showing me ripped css html page

Comment: What is `ripped css html page`? For css/image/js use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: thank you after direct url http://  css and javasript linking showing page is showing exactly i want .. i have four more page. FAQ.php?view=siez_chart,  FAQ.php?view=shipping how can i extend this .htaccess code

Comment: You will need those 2 set of rules for each page, very similar to what I showed in my answer.

Comment: You can't place code in comments. Edit you question and paste it there.

Comment: Just `RewriteRule ^ /FAQ/SizeChart/? [R=301,L]` is wrong you need `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+FAQ\.php\?view=size_chart [NC]` before that.

Comment: ok i as you said i did and its working.. but when i click on second link after last one its going to http://www.bestsports.ca/FAQ/SizeChart/FAQ.php?view=why_best

Comment: thank i got it now i have to change link in href ?view=why_best to faq/whybest/ after that its working fine

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for this problem. It is difficult to understand current problem with lots of comments and edits.